# Show possible choices of a model field in a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In my exercise I have a Django model of a book, having a field "genre". This field has the following option choices

```
GENRES_CHOICE = (
                 ('ADV','Adventure'),
                 ('FAN','Fantasy'),
                 ('POE','Poetry'),
                )
```

and the model field is

```
 genre = models.CharField(max_length = 3, blank = False, choices = GENRES_CHOICE, db_index = True, editable = False)
```

In my template I would like to show to the user the list of the genres (Adventure, Fantasy, Poetry) and hava available the keys, in order to possibly use them as parameters.

In order to do so, I would like to have a function that returns the data structure GENRES_CHOICE, but I am not able to. How to solve this problem?

EDIT:
more code details

appname= mybookshelf, file -> models/Book.py

```
# possible choices for the gerne field
GENRES_CHOICE = (
                  ('ADV','Adventure'),
                  ('FAN','Fantasy'),
                  ('POE','Poetry'),
                )

class Book(models.Model):
    """
    This is the book model

   ...

 ## ATTRIBUTES (better use init, but in Django not always possible)
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 64, blank = False, unique = True, primary_key = True,   editable = False)
    """ unique id for the element """

        genre = models.CharField(max_length = 3, blank = False, choices = GENRES_CHOICE, db_index = True, editable = False)
    """ book genre """

    published_date = models.DateField(null = True, auto_now_add = True, editable = False)
    """ date of publishing """
```

Then, into another file, lets say MyFunctions.py I have

```
from mybookshelf.models import GENRES_CHOICE 

    def getBookCategories():
        """
        This function returns the possible book categories 

        categories = GENRES_CHOICE 

        return categories
```

Comment: Did you use modelform? or you want it to directly show in the template?

Comment: No, I am not using a modelform, I would like to know if it is possible to "directly" show the data in the template.

Comment: yeah it's possible. Just call GENRES_CHOICE from your model into view

Comment: I am not able to :( I am writing a function (after importing the model, of course)


def getCategories():
 ...
        categories = GENRES_CHOICE
 ...
    return categories

and it doesnt work.

I also tried with  categories = ModelName.GENRES_CHOICE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**views.py**

```
from app_name.models import GENRES_CHOICE

def view_name(request):
    ...............

    return render(request, 'page.html', {
        'genres': GENRES_CHOICE
    })
```

**page.html**

```
{% for genre in genres %}
    {{genre.1}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother, but this doesnt work to me. I have an import error. I also tried to "from app_name.models import model_name" and to refer as categories = GENRES_CHOICE or categories = model_name.GENRES_CHOICE and in any case it doesnt work. :/ as you can imagine I'm at my very first django experience (and actually the reference doc is not helping me that much)

Comment: @RobertoParrotto   that's ok just post your models.py codes and will try to fix it

Comment: @RobertoParrotto put your genre choices outside the book model so that the other functions can use it globally

Comment: I've put it in the same file, outside the model, but still I can't import it nor use it :((

Comment: is your models code save in book.py? appname= mybookshelf, file -> models/Book.py

Comment: from mybookshelf.models import Book  - works
from mybookshelf.models import GENRES_CHOICE  - does not work

Comment: Please update your codes above about your current models.py now

Comment: And your views.py code where you call the GENRES_CHOICE. I would like to compare it. Thanks

Comment: I solved :) it was indeed an import error. I wrote "from mybookshelf.models.Book import GENRES_CHOICE" and it works. Your help was very useful to me to find the right solution: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this is what you are after, but if you want to show the user the list of GENRES_CHOICE you can do this in your templete:

```
{% for choice_id, choice_label in genres %}
           <p> {{ choice_id }} - {{ choice_label }}   </p>        
{% endfor %}
```

ofcourse pass GENRES_CHOICE as genres

Answer (score 0):

You could use the get_modelfield_display() method in your template, e.g.:

```
{{ book.get_genre_display }}
```